# Maximum number of coplanar atoms in difluorotrimethylphosphorane

Tags: molecular-structure, hybridization, valence-bond-theory

> In $\ce{PF2(CH3)3},$ what is the maximum number of atoms lying in one plane?

$\ce{P}$ is the central atom with the hybridization $\mathrm{sp^3d}.$ Two $\ce{F}$ atoms will form axial bonds with it, while three $\ce{CH3}$-groups form equatorial bonds. Each of these $\ce{CH3}$-groups has tetrahedral geometry, which means that one $\ce{H}$ atom lies in the same plane as the $\ce{C}$ central atom.
Thus, two $\ce{F}$ atoms, one $\ce{P}$ atom, one $\ce{C}$ atom and one $\ce{H}$ atom with it, totalling five atoms, lie in the same plane.

Is my attempt correct?

Comment: What if you try another plane?

Comment: @Ivan Neretin Which?

Comment: For one, you state $\ce{F-P-F}$ are aligned in axial manner, _without_ noting H, nor C.  Based on this assumption, this adds up to three.  But since the axial direction is orthogonal to the equatorial plane, count what's possible there; build a model and don't forget that methyl / $\ce{CH3}$-groups bound by $\sigma$-bonds may rotate like propellers, thus form multiple conformers.

Comment: @Buttonwood Ah, I see. There should be 7 atoms in the equatorial plane ($P$, 3 $C$ atoms and 3 $H$ atoms).

Comment: @IshanJMukherjee _At maximum_, true; because molecules are flexible and dynamic /  vibrate (in IR spectroscopy occasionally you occasionally hear a colloquial «breathing vibration»).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seven is correct (the OP found this in the comments).  The methyl carbons are in the equatorial plane and each one can rotate a hydrogen atom into this plane.  In fact the hydrogen atoms fit well with this conformation so it's actually favorable.